# Plan on how to replace pipes from PEX to 3 end points

Tags: plumbing

I am looking for help with planning to replace the galvanized pipes leading from a PEX pipe as the water source to 3 end points:

1. The faucet in the sink above
2. The pipe through the wall leading to outdoor spigot
3. The washing machine

The galvanized pipe is corroding inside and should be replaced. My best guess is that the installation is about 30 years old now.

What is the simplest way to install a splitter that will take the cold water from the incoming PEX pipe and send it to the 3 installations.

I need a on/off valve at the source (PEX) and one before the outdoor spigot (for winter). The existing valve at the dishwasher line can be dropped unless there is some specific requirement for it.

Can someone give me a list of things I should buy and some basic installation guidelines?

I am in Denmark so we are mostly metric although I think some pipe sizes are still listed in inches. For example, that elbow joint is marked as a 1/2" fitting.

Thanks!

[image]